# How to search and replace this white space with an underscore?

Tags: python, regex

```
text = 'Captain Fawcett英国 美国'
```

There is a space between 'Captain' and 'Fawcett' and I want to replace this space with an underscore:

```
text = 'Captain_Fawcett英国'
```

and the replacement condition is that if the preceding and exceeding char is [a-zA-Z]. I want to do something like this in Python:

```
pattern = '[a-zA-Z](\s)[a-zA-Z]'
text = re.sub(pattern, "_", text)
```

But this doesn't get what I want.

Comment: ^ The search term you're looking for are "positive lookahead / lookbehind"

Comment: @khelwood, I edit my string. There could be multiple spaces and only certain spaces between ascii characters should be replaced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
re.sub(r'(?<=[a-zA-Z])\s+(?=[a-zA-Z])', '_', s)
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/XLENcr/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [a-zA-Z]                 any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to 'Z'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [a-zA-Z]                 any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to 'Z'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```